# Как скрыть файл json на сервере Django

Tags: python, django

Сервер на Django. Там находится файл json. Программа обращается к нему и получает данные. Необходимо чтобы никто кроме программы не смог получить к нему доступ. Так как есть программы wireshark и прочие узнать ссылку очень легко. Как можно скрыть ссылку или сделать определенный доступ.

Comment: Решайте причину, а не симптомы. Почему вообще в вашем случае кто попало может поставить wireshark и выполнить перехват?

Comment: Погуглите в сторону `htaccess django`.